# What is the meaning of "creaming somebody's spinach over somebody"

Tags: phrases, idioms

I have been watching "Family Guy" recently and Peter says:
"my wife's been creaming her spinach over him"

What does it mean? I went from top to bottom of Google and found nothing. It's really weird because any time I search an idiom or a phrase, I could find it right away. Why this is not found anywhere?

Comment: It's not a phrase I've ever heard. My guess is that it was invented for that episode.

Comment: Semi-crude reference to "becoming aroused", most likely

Comment: Shows like Family Guy often make up phrases like this, which aren't in common use but convey (or try to) what they mean through association. The point is to say something that the censor wouldn't normally allow them to say - but they can't stop it if the phrase doesn't really mean anything.  Gus has given you a pretty good idea of what it iws intended to mean. More discussion of the subject here: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/GettingCrapPastTheRadar

Comment: It's a play on the vulgar expression "creamed her panties."

Answer (score 3):

It was a nonce usage -- that is, the writers of the show invented the expression just for that joke.

As for what it means, "cream" is slang that here means "to become sexually aroused".  All the online definitions I could find linked it specifically to semen (including [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cream)), but in real life, as in this quotation, I have only heard it in the context of women.

"Creamed spinach" is simply [a way to prepare spinach](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/paula-deen/creamed-spinach-recipe2.html).

Together, they mean... well, meaning is in the eye of the beholder.

Comment: It's probably because they didn't think they'd get away with saying "creaming her jeans"

Comment: "Creaming her jeans" would not be funny.

Answer (score -1):

**Creamed Spinach**

When a woman has too many organs without washing her pubes and the result resembles creamed spinach.

Lois was basically masturbating a lot to Dallas Portland without washing, and all her dried up juices in her pubes looked like creamed spinach.

Source: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=creamed%20spinach